# Answers appear sorted by date and not by the vote count

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, user-interface

When I read the question

[How to correct outliers once detected for time series data forecasting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69874/how-to-correct-outliers-once-detected-for-time-series-data-forecasting)

the answers are in an unexpected order, based on how the answers appear in StackOverflow. Specifically, the answers are not ordered in descending order by vote count. Instead the votes (in order are):

-1, 3, 0, 5, 0

Similarly for the question

[How do R and Python complement each other in data science?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238726/how-do-r-and-python-complement-each-other-in-data-science)

Is this by design, or just a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It's by design.**  You control the order by clicking one of the three options at the right in a banner preceding the answers:

[image]

Comment: Ah, thanks. Missed that. :)